# Doctrine: No custom field type appliement in CASE WHEN

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm trying to apply a custom property type within a CASE WHEN condition.

My custom Type:

```
<?php

[NAMESPACE GOES HERE]

[USE STATEMENTS GO HERE]

class AesType extends Type
{
    const AES = 'aes';

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::AES;
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'TEXT';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
    [OPERATIONS TO MODIFY $value. THIS WORKS WELL IN MOST CASES]

        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
    [OPERATIONS TO MODIFY $value. THIS WORKS WELL IN MOST CASES]

        return $value;
    }
}
```

If i do fetches in a simple select everything works fine. But if i "fetch" or "apply" values in a CASE WHEN it seems that my type modifications are not applied.

Bellow is a code snippet of the relevant part.

```
$fieldsStatic = [];

while($dateTimeLoop <= $dateTimeForeCast) {
  $date = $dateTimeLoop->format('Y-m-d');
  $selection = 'CASE WHEN (((DATE(salaryContract.dateFrom) <= \'' . $date . '\') AND (salaryContract.dateUntil IS NULL)) OR ((salaryContract.dateUntil IS NOT NULL) AND (DATE(salaryContract.dateUntil) >= \'' . $date . '\') AND (DATE(salaryContract.dateFrom) <= \'' . $date . '\'))) THEN salary.amount ELSE \'-\' END';
  $as = 'AS salary_' . $dateTimeLoop->format('Y') . '_' . $dateTimeLoop->format('m');
  $fieldsDynamic[] = $selection . ' ' . $as;

  $dateTimeLoop->add(new \DateInterval('P' . Salary::CSV_EXPORT_INTERVAL_MONTHS . 'M'));
}

$fields = array_merge($fieldsStatic, $fieldsDynamic);

$query = self::getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()->select($fields)->from(self::getModel(), 'salary');

$result = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

If i know dump $result the value of salary.amount ist still AES encrypted but the type of amount is declared as "aes" like so: (This is still only the relevant part of the model)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="emd_salary",
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks
 */
class Salary
{
    const CSV_EXPORT_INTERVAL_MONTHS = 1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="aes", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $amount;
}
```

I have added the type correctly to my setup routine like so:

```
Type::addType('aes', AesType::class);

$entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('aes', 'aes');
```